# How to check a string against a symbols whitelist a functional way in Scala?

Tags: string, scala

I need to guarantee a string only contains allowed symbols. Now I do it this way:

```
def isCorrect(s: String, allowedChars: String): Boolean = {
  s.distinct.foreach(c => {
    if (!allowedChars.contains(c))
      return false
  })

  true
}
```

Needless to say this does not look too pretty. Is there a better, more functional way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know if it is the most functional way to do it, but you can do this:

```
def isCorrect(s: String, allowedChars: String): Boolean = {
    return s.distinct.forall(c => allowedChars.contains(c))
}
```

the **distinct** isnt really necessary.

Comment: You can omit the `return` and the braces. You can also write only `allowedChars.contains` as the content of the parenthesis. `... = s.forall(allowedChars.contains)`.

Comment: @Ziggystar, that appears to be incorrect. `def isCorrect(s: String, allowedChars: String): Boolean = {  s.forall(allowedChars.contains)}` gives `error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.lang.CharSequence => Boolean
 required: Char => Boolean
        s.forall(allowedChars.contains)}`

Comment: @ziggstar probably means: "def isCorrect(s: String, allowedChars: Seq[String]) = s.forall(allowedChars.contains)", which is cool, I often forget that "_" can be passed in implicitly to a function, like "list foreach println"

Comment: @virtualeyes, I tihnk you mean `allowChars: Seq[Char]` there (which does work and keeps a compatible signature). Updated my answer with a revised version

Comment: @Paul right, I just pasted in REPL and made a Seq[String] to get it to compile, did not pay attention to the actual function requirement, allowed chars ;-)

Answer (score 19):

For the record, you can make this a little more generic by not limiting yourself to strings of characters, and a little more functional (in my view) by switching the order of arguments and using two argument lists. Here's how I'd write it:

```
def isCorrect[A](allowed: Set[A])(s: Seq[A]) = s forall allowed
```

Now you can treat this method as a function and "partially apply" it to create more specialized functions:

```
val isDigits = isCorrect("0123456789".toSet) _
val isAs = isCorrect(Set('A')) _
```

Which allows you to do the following:

```
scala> isDigits("218903")
res1: Boolean = true

scala> isAs("218903")
res2: Boolean = false

scala> isDigits("AAAAAAA")
res3: Boolean = false

scala> isAs("AAAAAAA")
res4: Boolean = true
```

Or you could still just use something like `isCorrect("abcdr".toSet)("abracadabra")`.

Comment: Though I think I am going to keep with string.forall variant, I appreciate your answer a lot. If could I'd upvote it twice and more... Thanks, Travis.

Comment: just woke up and the penny drops, bing, thanks for a concrete "useful" example of partial application, Travis.

Comment: @Travis Tyvm for posting this answer. My understanding of the utility of partial functions has been blurry. Your example is very clear, very concise and at least for me a very common kind of pattern I encounter in most of my configuration file like processing.

Answer (score 4):

```
def isCorrect(s:String, allowedChars:String):Boolean = { 
        s.forall{allowedChars.contains(_)}
    }
```

Or, even more succinctly, following @ziggystar's suggestion:

```
def isCorrect(s: String, allowedChars: Seq[Char]) = s forall allowedChars.contains
```

Comment: Thanks. Since you have both given a correct answer, though you've given it somewhat earlier, I hope you wouldn't mind if I accept Rodrigo's one to let him gain some reputation points.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't more functional, but uses a regexp:

```
def isCorrect(s: String, allowedChars: String): Boolean =
  s.matches ("^["+ allowedChars +"]*$")
```

Since regex are often optimized, I would consider this approach in performance critical code - not without testing, measuring, and maybe with precompiled patterns - if appropriate for the problem at hand.

As more functional flavoured I see Travis code.

Comment: .. and goes wrong in interesting ways if allowedChars contains ']' (or '^' as the first character.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Use `s.matches ("^["+ escape (allowedChars) +"]*$")
` then. `escape` has to be written for that purpose. :)

Comment: Ah! So that's an example of the saying: some people when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions" Now they have TWO problems.