# What does the _ parameter signify in this context?

Tags: scala

What is the parameter "_" in below method call signify ?

Is this a wildcard that accepts a parameter of any type ?

```
val integerSorter = msort[Int]((a, b) => a < b) _
```

The method msort signature :

```
  def msort[T](less: (T, T) => Boolean)(xs: List[T]): List[T] = {
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way to explain this is probably to let the compiler do most of the explaining—just try the first line without the underscore:

```
scala> val integerSorter = msort[Int]((a, b) => a < b)
<console>:11: error: missing arguments for method msort;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
       val integerSorter = msort[Int]((a, b) => a < b)
                                     ^
```

So there you have it—the `msort` method has two parameter lists, but you've only passed arguments for the first, and the trailing underscore is the syntax that Scala provides to tell the compiler that you want partial application in that situation.

(If you try that line in the REPL *with* the underscore, you'll see that the inferred type of `integerSorter` is `List[Int] => List[Int]`, so to answer your second question, no, the underscore doesn't allow you to provide a parameter of any type.)

For more information, see section 6.7 of [the language specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf):

> The expression `e _` is well-formed if `e` is of method type or if `e` is a
>   call-by-name parameter. If `e` is a method with parameters, `e _`
>   represents `e` converted to a function type by eta expansion
>   (§6.26.5).

Reading the section on eta expansion may also be helpful.

Comment: why define it like this, should this not be an explicit call ? So change the msort function definition to "  def msort[T](less: (T, T) => Boolean , xs: List[T]): List[T] = {" and then call using "val integerSorter = msort[Int]( ((a, b) => a < b) , List(1,2,3))" I just don't see what advantages this gives other than to confuse...

Comment: @blue-sky: Partial application can often be a really helpful tool for structuring your code—see for example [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10238391/334519).

Answer (score 2):

msort takes two parameters, a function that returns a boolean, and a list of items to be sorted. the function integerSorter supplies the first parameter, and the underscore represents the list that still needs to be specified. look up currying (http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/135.html) for a more detailed explanation.